# Can you move a RAID from a dedicated controller to on-board motherboard raid?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid-10

So currently I have a very old raid card that I have 4 drives attached to because at the time my Mobo did not have enough sata ports. Now much later I have a new motherboard and the raid controller card itself is causing me issues due to its age. I would like to transfer the raid to the one from my motherboard. Raid 10 if that helps

Note Motherboard is MSI Gaming M7 and this is the current raid card [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Port-Controller-Adapter-PCISATA4R1/dp/B0001Y7PU8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001Y7PU8) . I have tried just putting the drives in the mobo with no luck.

Comment: Did you configure and format the drives as a RAID array after putting them in the mobo? Did you make sure your backup was up to date first? Don't skip steps.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you cannot. This is because the implementation of the RAID systems are different. The only way that works 100% is to copy files elsewhere, setup a new RAID with the motherboard and then copy files back there.

Answer (score 1):

The matter is complex.

While direct reconnection works on similar controllers, RAID controller manufacturers often do not use the same RAID algorithm and format. RAID table information written by one manufacturer's adapter will not be mandatory compatible with another manufacturer's adapter information. Different companies implement their own unique RAID table data information.

To migrate from another manufacturer's controller, backup and verify the data, then delete the current RAID array. Install the new RAID controller, create a new RAID, restore the data.

As a certainty, it is not possible to migrate RAID Arrays from ICP GDT Code Controllers to Adaptec-like RAID Controllers, however it is possible to move Arrays from newer ICP RAID Controller models, on U160/U320 SCSI, SAS or SATA that are not GDT code based.

As a test, you can just try, it can't hurt as long as you do not edit any RAID information. Set your new controller in RAID mode (this is 100% mandatory), connect all drives and see what happens.